# How to track htaccess redirect in google analytics?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, google-analytics

I have htaccess redirects to a domain so as my personal url manual shortener i.e. 
*Google click link to domain.com/document*

It's really handy but google analytics don't seem to pick it up I was using wrapping my link in bitly and then redirecting threw them but is there a way so that I would have those stats in my Google Analytics console?

P.S. This is what kind of redirecting I am using https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file
I am mostly redirecting to outside sources meaning I don't have the option to track it at the destination.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. This question has already been asked and answered there: [How to keep track of how many hits on a redirect page with Google Analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61505/how-to-keep-track-of-how-many-hits-on-a-redirect-page-with-google-analytics)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283057/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf) and [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283033/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so) this question is not at all off-topic for SO so close vote is wrong. This has been discussed again and again and it has been settled already that most of the rewrite rules are created and maintained by developers of the web applications/frameworks.

Comment: Mod rewrite questions are fine here when they have a programming aspect.   If you posted a question with rewrite rules in it and ask how to fix them, that would be programming.    Questions like this about tracking redirects in GA are not programming and a prefect fit for [webmasters.se].